# Steam games are unplayable on Wayland (22.04)

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, games, steam, wayland

I'm facing a problem I didn't expect on a recent clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 (with Gnome), where I simply cannot play any Steam games on a Wayland session while using the most recent proprietary Nvidia driver (530 on a RTX 2070 and a desktop without any other dedicated graphics card): the game will launch as a complete slideshow with broken graphics and tearing, while the same games will play flawlessly on a X11 session. Is almost as if the gpu isn't being used.

I understand that there might be *some* performance loss on Wayland due to issues with the Nvidia driver, but not the way it is happening since I've played these games on Wayland before with relatively reasonable success and everything else is working perfectly on the Wayland session for me (better than on X11 even, I might say).

It's relevant to say that I am using the Steam flatpak since the snap package cannot access my external drive, from what I've seen, but it doesn't matter since the problem happens on the deb version of Steam as well. Also, changing to earlier versions of the driver like 525, 515 etc does nothing for it as well.

So, how can I troubleshoot what's wrong here? Am I missing some graphics related package or configuration?

Comment: Steam and Wayland support don't go hand in hand.  You may actually have to just use the X session instead of Wayland to run your games in Steam via Steam Play.